# How can I overlay text to multiple table cells?

Tags: jquery, html-table, append, overlay

I want to overlay text to my multiple table cells. In my case to the cells with data-date from `2018-04-02` to `2018-04-04`. So as a result it should look like this:

[image: example]

But I am only able to append the text to one cell.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".main-table").clone(true).appendTo('#table-scroll').addClass('clone');
});


$('.table-wrap').scrollLeft($('[data-date="2018-04-01"]').offset().left - 82);


$('[data-date="2018-04-02"]').css("background-color", "yellow");
$('[data-date="2018-04-03"]').css("background-color", "yellow");
$('[data-date="2018-04-04"]').css("background-color", "yellow");

$('[data-date="2018-04-02"]').append("mycontent");
```

```css
.table-scroll {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table-scroll table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table-scroll th,
.table-scroll td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.clone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.clone th,
.clone td {
  visibility: hidden
}

.clone td,
.clone th {
  border-color: transparent
}

.clone tbody th {
  visibility: visible;
}

.clone .fixed-side {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  border: none;
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.clone thead,
.clone tfoot {
  background: transparent;
}

.gantt-h {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #b0b0b0;
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.last {
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.gantt td {
  border-right: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
}

.today{
background-color:pink;
width:100px;
cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
  <div class="table-wrap">
    <table class="main-table table gantt">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" scope="col" class="left-h" style="border-bottom:2px solid #f4f4f4;color:#b0b0b0">Task</th>

          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h" style="font-weight:normal;color:#b0b0b0;">30 Mar</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">31 Mar</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">01 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">02 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">03 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">04 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">05 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">06 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">07 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">08 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">09 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">10 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">11 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">12 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">13 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">14 Apr</th>
          <th scope="col" class="gantt-h">15 Apr</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side project"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> Projekt 1</th>

          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> blue</th>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-03-30"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-03-31"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-01"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-02"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-03"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-04"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-05"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-06"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-07"></td>
          <td data-row="2" data-date="2018-04-08"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> green</th>

          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> yellow</th>

          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> pink</th>

          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="fixed-side" style="padding-left:27px"><i class="fa fa-file-o" style="color:#9e9e9e"></i> orange</th>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems that the `colspan` attribute would be the easiest solution here.

Comment: You mean like this: `$('[data-date="2018-04-02"]').append("mycontent").attr('colspan',3);`

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

Comment: You do need to set a fixed width to the columns else it won't work. An example with overflow: https://fiddle.jshell.net/fqmnzvv8/12/